# RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception')

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack and Elasticsearch for my app. I have loaded all the requirements and trying to search my indices using search.html

But whenever I tried to retrieve the results using an API at http://localhost:8000/search, I am getting the below error and I have googled much about this but couldn't able to get any help:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception')
```

search query in views.py

```
def search(uri, term):
    query = json.dumps({
        "query": {
        "bool": {
        "filter": {"term":"channel"}
            }
        }
    })
    response = request.get(uri, data=query)
    results = json.loads(response.text)
    return results
```

Recording model in models.py

```
class Recordings(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, related_name="recordings")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    duration = models.DurationField(default=0)
    file_size = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    file_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    proceed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'date'
        ordering = ['-date']
        index_together = ["date", "channel"]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{channel} {date}'.format(Channel=self.channel, date=self.date)
```

search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from matches.models import Recordings

class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    channel = indexes.CharField(model_attr='channel')
    date = indexes.CharField(model_attr='date')
    file_size = indexes.CharField(model_attr='file_size')
    file_location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='file_location')

    def get_model(self):
        return Recordings
```

search.html

```
{% block content %}

<h2>Recordings search</h2>

    <form method="get" action="" class="form" role="form">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
        </div>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>
            <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>channel</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>file_size</th>
                        <th>file_location</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for result in page.object_list %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ result.channel }}</td>
                            <td>{{ result.date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ result.file_size }}</td>
                            <td>{{ result.file_location }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% empty %}
                        <tr>No results found.</tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            <table>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endblock content %}

{% block extrajs %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result_table').DataTable({
        "searching": false
    });
} );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

recordings_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.channel }}
{{ object.date }}
{{ object.file_size }}
{{ object.file_location }}
```

Comment: That would suggest your Elasticsearch query is malformed, post the code for your search view.

Comment: I will post the entire code and edit the question. Please wait a minute

Comment: @rafalmp I have edited the question. Please reply

Comment: I guess the query `{"query": {"bool": {"filter": {"term": {"channel": term}}}}}` should work, but since you use Haystack, why not use its [SearchQuerySet](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchqueryset_api.html?

Comment: I have referred to http://nanvel.name/2013/07/django-haystack-example for working with the app. Here the search query is not mentioned.